# Redirect to other page in ionic framework v3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic framework. I am trying to redirect to other page on button click in ionic framework version 3. I did not get enough source on this. I tried `location()` and `go()` functions but it did not work.

This is my code in newpage.html :

```
<button ion-button block (click)="click()">Click me</button>
```

This is my code in newpage.ts :

```
  click() {
  this.go('/HomePage');
  }
```

Comment: May I ask, why don't you read the [navigation-related docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) in the first place?

Comment: Sorry i was keen on looking for button click. Did not think there could be a way to redirect from nav on button click

Comment: Np, just mentioned that because navigation in Ionic is not as simple as it may look, so you'd definitely need to read the docs to avoid some bugs/issues. There are a lot of things to consider for your question, like _is that the root component?_, _do you want to set that page as root, or just push it?_, and so on...

Comment: Okay thank u for the suggestion

Comment: @sebaferreras - Hey found answer for setting as root component and just pushing it. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `[NavController][1]` from `ionic-angular`. Its `push()`-method pushes a new view onto the navigation stack. This means that you can use the `NavController` `pop()`-method to go back to this page.

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
// IMPORT HOMEPAGE IF NOT LAZY-LOADED
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

export class NewPage{
    constructor(private navCtrl:NavController){}

    // IF LAZY-LOADED
    click(){
        this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
    }

    // IF NOT LAZY-LOADED
    click(){
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }
}
```

**According to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/):** 
"If the page has an `<ion-navbar>`, a back button will automatically be added to the pushed view."

Comment: Its saying `Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: HomePage`

Comment: Hey if i dont want back arrow instead i want menu icon. How do i do that? Thats after redirecting